# Mayim Acharonim with a cup?

Tags: netilat-yadayim-washing, meal-seudah, water

(Asked because it seems to have been neglected from the answers to [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11120/whats-the-deal-with-all-the-washings).)

Is one required to wash Mayim Acharonim from of a cup (or vessel that is kosher for Mayim Rishonim)? Must one use *"koach gavra"*?

Note: If I understood it correctly, ther [Gemara Hullin 105a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=31&daf=105&format=pdf) discusses washing *into* a vessel, but that isn't what I'm asking about.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. The [**Kaf HaHaim 181:10**](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9087&hilite=01bef0b5-2f26-4ca9-b1ae-de4f842630b0&st=%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%9D%20%D7%90%D7%97%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%9D&pgnum=169) rules that one isn't required to use a Keli that is proper for Netilat Yadayim (see Levush and Kol Bo Siman 23).

Comment: In fact, IIRC, the Mishnah Berurah states that one needs to use the same amount of water as is required for washing prior to eating (up to the wrists, etc.). This would indicate, to me at least, that if the cup one has for after waters is a small one, especially if one has to pass it on to others, the proper thing to do would be to get up and go to the sink to wash one's hands under the tap and not at the table with the cup (as is the more common practice).

Answer (score 4):

From [HalachaForToday.com](http://halachafortoday.com/archivesSeuda.aspx)

> 1) Mayim Achronim does not require a utensil, nor does it require "Koach Gavra, force of a human" like the washing of Netilas Yadayim.

The source is from the [Mishna Berurah, 181:21](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49624&st=&pgnum=167)

---

As far as whether to wash into a keili or not, the same site says this:

> Rather, the water should be washed into a utensil that is designated as a receptacle for the water, which should then be disposed of. (See Biur Halacha Siman 181:2)
>
> However, if the water is being washed onto the floor that is under the table, where nobody will walk, it is permitted to do so. Still, if a utensil is available in which to wash, that is better than doing on the floor under the table (Mishna Berura Siman 181:4-6. See also Shulchan Aruch HaRav Siman 180:4)
>
> 2) Mayim Achronim may be washed directly into the sink, as people who are stringent to use a Revi'is as the Gaon of Vilna held, do in any case. Some maintain that the water must be washed into a utensil, and not in the sink, however the prevalent minhag is not to require this. (See Shu"t Yabia Omer Vol. 5 Siman 2 and Likutei MaHarich end of HanHogas Seudah quoting the Shl"a HaKadosh.)

Comment: הנוהגים ליטול מים אחרונים על ידי הכנסת ידיהם לקערה עם מים, יש להם על מה שיסמוכו (Yalkut Yosef vol. 3 pg. 248). In other words, Lechatehila you would have to pour MA according to him, and Lechatehila it does require Kowah Gavra.

Comment: HaRav BenSion Musafi Shelit"a once said in his Shiur that "Yesh Al Mi Lismoch" doesn't mean he holds that way, rather, the people that do that are in good hands. I meant to say, according to him, it requires Koah Gavra and pouring.

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zAaZ7mRBRGM&feature=related in this Shiur he says that Kelal.

Comment: @Vram well, the Zivhe Sedek (vol. 3 Siman 35) completely permits this act of placing the hands into e.g. a bowl of water.

Comment: @Vram And also BTW using a sink would be Mutar (Yalkut Yosef vol. 3 181:4).

Comment: @HachamGabriel I misunderstood the quote you brought. It seems he holds that lechatchila it should be poured, although not necessarily through koach gavra.

Comment: You are correct. Koah Gavra isn't necessary.