# which activities require the use of a cup and which require plain washing?

Tags: halacha, netilat-yadayim-washing, shulchan-aruch

The shulchan aruch lists a bunch of things that require you to do netilat yadyim (siman 23, saif 18):

"The instances when one must do N’tilas Yadayim are the following: One who gets up from his bed, one who goes out of the bathroom and from the bathhouse, one who cuts his nails, one who removes his shoes, touches his feet, one who scratches his head. There are those who add one who walks between the dead, touches a dead body, examines his garments for lice, has relations, touched a louse, and touched his body with his hand. If one did one of these things and did not wash his hands, if he is a torah scholar, his learning will be forgotten. And if he is not a torah scholar, he goes crazy."

Do all these cases require a cup or only before eating bread and waking up?

Comment: dupe? http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/11120/759