# Insomnia and Modeh Ani

Tags: halacha, minhag, tefilla, sleep, morning-day

I am wondering what is done in the case of people who have insomnia. I usually sleep about 4 hours a night and I wake during those hours maybe 5 or 6 times.

I got into the habit of saying Modeh ani as soon as my eyes open 'in the morning' but recently I find myself saying it anytime I open my eyes so sometimes 6 or so times a night. Is it proper to just say it in the morning when I wake or as I am doing it now 6 or so times a night.

I know it sounds like a request for personal advice but I mean in general for people who suffer insomnia and sleep disorders is there anything written about this?

Comment: Yupp. Makes sense to me.

Comment: Although it does raise more questions. I do netilas yadayim after each time I use the restroom. Seems like that thread says you only do it ' when waking' same with modeh ani. Seems I have been overzealous in my observances. Probably keeping kosher too strictly too :)

Comment: Please keep doing so! You wash in the morning for many reasons incl. removing impure spirit from the hands. You wash after the restroom for cleanliness and to prepare for tfila. See here for instance https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11120/whats-the-deal-with-all-the-washings. But just to be clear, after bathroom you need to wash but don't need a keli which is a chumrah. See http://dinonline.org/2015/04/08/washing-hands-after-bathroom/ and https://www.ou.org/torah/machshava/tzarich-iyun/tzarich_iyun_washing_after_leaving_the_washroom/

Comment: There is even the Chabad minhag of washing with the three pours on each when waking and not saying netilas. Then relieve yourself and come back out and wash thrice again with the prayer this time. So many customs how is one not to be a makhmir!