# Was divrei kabalah practiced before the nevi'im?

Tags: history, hashkafah-philosophy, halacha-theory

The Nevi'im sometimes got prophecies and wrote them down in [Nevi'im or Kesuvim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tanakh), and from those prophecies, we learn divrei kabalah. We learn things like oneg, mimtzo cheftzecha, and daber davar on Shabbos, from Yeshayahu; or we learn things like moshav leitzim from Tehilim; etc.

My question is this: Before those things were written in Tanach. were they practiced? For example, before Yeshayahu came, was there a requirement for oneg, just that it wasn't written down?

([Related](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/16973/ban-on-shabas-fasts-derived-from-lechem-hapanim))

Comment: related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/16046/759

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I later found what may be an answer to this question.

[Rabbeinu Bachya](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9712&st=&pgnum=22) writes that all of the books of the nevi'im were given at Sinai, but permission wasn't given to write them down until those prophets themselves came. If so, it seems that divrei kabalah stood even before the nevi'im came.

Comment: But you asked if they were practiced, and I have to imagine that if the books of neviim were given at sinai, they were hidden until the relevant story happened. If so, who's to say they kept law X before it was revealed?

Comment: It appears from R' Bachya's wording that the law had been handed down as tradition, and the prophets came and supported it on a pasuk.

Comment: Thats not what you said in the answer.